# Monster Search - Loop (string search + integer insert)

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, ms-access

I have a large string(over 255 char) called strMonsterEssay.

There is a string character repeated throughout this essay with exact format like Monster X and I want to be able to find the largest monster number. Throughout the essay there is Monster 1, Monster 2...Monster X. Note, there is a max number of 99 monsters possible.

At the end of the code I want to be able to say something like "There are 25 Monsters".

I don't know the syntax to enter an integer into a 'like' search loop. This is the code I have so far and I would appreciate some help, please:

```
Dim MonsterNum As Integer 
Dim strHowManyMonsters As String

MonsterNum = 1

For MonsterNum 1 to 99

    If (NOT strMonsterEssay like ("*Monster&Char(32)&'"MonsterNum + 1"'*") And strMonsterEssay like ("*Monster&Char(32)&'"MonsterNum"'*") Then strHowManyMonsters = "There are '"MonsterNum"' Monsters."

    Else: strHowManyMonsters = "There are no Monsters."
    
    End If

Next MonsterNum
```

Comment: Aren't the "Monster xx" consecutive numbers? Can they be only "Monster 3" and "Monster 56"?

Comment: If the answer at my above question is yes and there are involved only the two above monsters, do you need to know the number of monsters (2) (like "There are 2 Monsters"), or 56 ("largest monster number")? Beside that, may the same monster number have more occurrences inside the big string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim MonsterNum As Integer
Dim strHowManyMonsters As String

strHowManyMonsters = "There are no Monsters."

For MonsterNum = 99 To 1 Step -1
  
    If strMonsterEssay Like "*[mM]onster " & MonsterNum & "*" Then
        strHowManyMonsters = "There are " & MonsterNum & " Monsters."
        Exit For
    End If
  
Next MonsterNum
```

Note the usage of `[mM]` to test make the search not case-sensitive. I think it might be a better option to use VBA's `Instr()` function like this:

```
If InStr(1, strMonsterEssay, "Monster " & MonsterNum, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

Also note the backward counting.

Comment: Super Symmetry, Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the next function, please. If all existing 'Monster' strings are followed by different numbers, the number does not matter. It is enough to count `Monster`.

```
Function CountMonsters(FullString As String, strMonster As String) As Long
    CountMonsters = UBound(Split(FullString, strMonster))
End Function
```

It can be called in this way:

```
Sub testFindMonsters()
  Dim strMonsterEssay As String
  strMonsterEssay = "Monster 1 and Monster 2 goes to school. Monster 3 is waitting for the first two..."
  MsgBox "There are " & CountMonsters(strMonsterEssay, "Monster") & " Monsters."
End Sub
```

If the "largest monster number" must be returned, the same function will be called in this way:

```
Sub testMaxMonsterNumber()
   Dim MonsterNum As Long, strMonsterEssay As String, maxNo As Long, i As Long
   Dim strHowManyMonsters As String
    
   strMonsterEssay = "Monster 1 and Monster 2 goes to school. Monster 3 is waiting for the first two. However, Monster 1 and Monster 2 saw Monster 3 waiting and went a different way. Monster 3 waited for a long time for Monster 1 and Monster 2 but they never showed up"
    For i = 99 To 1 Step -1
        If CountMonsters(strMonsterEssay, "Monster " & i) > 0 Then
            maxNo = i: Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If maxNo > 0 Then
       MsgBox "There are " & maxNo & " Monsters."
    Else
       MsgBox "There are no Monsters."
    End If
End Sub
```

But if "Monster 32 is waiting for the first two", it will return 32. I asked you about consecutive monsters number 'rule', but you did not say anything...

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the question expects numbered monsters, like monster 1, monster 76 and so on and they are trying to work out the largest monster number. I don't think the question is asking to count the number of occurrences of the word "monster". Again I could be wrong :)

Comment: @ Super Symmetry: What the desired answer described like **"There are 25 Monsters"** would mean? Starting from this meaning, I just think that his way of counting is 'special'. But I may be wrong, too... :) I asked something to clarify this aspect, but he does not say anything.

Comment: To use your example: `""Monster 1 and Monster 2 goes to school. Monster 3 is waitting for the first two. However, Monster 1 and Monster 2 saw Monster 3 waiting and went a different way. Monster 3 waited for a long time for Monster 1 and Monster 2 but they never showed up"`. How many monsters are there ? :)

Comment: My understaning is that he wants the largest associated number, in the above case 3. However, if we count the number of occurrences of "monster" we get 9.

Comment: @ Super Symmetry:  In such a case, when the same monster string may occur more then once, he must state that, I think.. But only him can clarify this aspect. I also admitted that I may  be wrong...

Comment: I agree the question could be more clear. But the clue for me is when the question said "I want to be able to find the largest monster number". Mind you, we could both be wrong lol